# Matomo ÄPI "Actions.getPageUrls" returns only 100 rows on rest api call

Tags: matomo

I am trying to fetch data from matomo api "Actions.getPageUrls" by using below code:

```js
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url="baseapi"

PARAMS = {'module': 'API', 
          'method':'Actions.getPageUrls', 
          'period' : 'range',
          'date': '2019-01-01,2020-01-01',
          'filter_limit' : '-1',
          'idSite': '1', 
          'format': 'JSON',
          'expanded' : '1',
          'token_auth': "tocken"}

r = requests.post(url = api_url, params = PARAMS, verify=False)
print(r.url)
matomo_df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
matomo_df.head()
matomo_df['label']
matomo_df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()[0]['subtable'])
matomo_df
```

But, it returns only 100 rows.

I want to get more than 100 rows. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is set to return only 100 rows, however when you set the 'filter-limit' to -1, it is suppose to return all the rows.Can you set the 'filter-limit' param to 10000 and try it.

Comment: No, even though it returns only 100 records. Is there any other way to get more than 100 records?

Comment: Have you tried to set the filter limit to 10,000? it should return up to 10,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the filter limit needing to be overridden in the call to the API, there are Matomo server configuration settings which control how many rows will be recorded during archiving.

Quoting the notes from the [default Matomo v4.15.1 config file](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/blob/4.15.1/config/global.ini.php#L577):

```ini
; during archiving, Matomo will limit the number of results recorded, for performance reasons

; maximum number of rows for any of the Actions tables (pages, downloads, outlinks)
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_actions = 500

; maximum number of rows for pages in categories (sub pages, when clicking on the + for a page category)
; note: should not exceed the display limit in Piwik\Actions\Controller::ACTIONS_REPORT_ROWS_DISPLAY
; because each subdirectory doesn't have paging at the bottom, so all data should be displayed if possible.
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_subtable_actions = 100
```

With that default configuration, at the top-level (`/blog`, `/help`, `/contact`, etc) you should be able to get up to 500 URLs, but for each sub-path (`/blog/*`, `/help/*`, `/contact/*`), only 100 URLs, with the remainder being grouped into "Other".